# Haxe stacktrace not showing on windows exec

Tags: haxe

I'm using Haxe to build a windows executable. When running the exec, error messages are really brief (eg: "Error: Null function") with no line numbers or stack traces.

I'm compiling the executable using the -debug flag (which is, in theory, supposed to enable a stacktrace on error) with no luck.

I looked into this page ( http://haxe.org/doc/cross/exceptions  ) and was hoping to override the default error-handling function, but there's no instructions on how to do that for a windows exec; only for flash/js/neko.

If I throw the game into a try/catch, I can manually grab the errors and call my own getTrace() and I'm happy, but it's gotten to the point where I'm not sure where to place my try/catch calls and really need to get this working.

Any tips?

Comment: I know that you’re using the C++ build target but I think you need to mention that in your question :). The resulting C++ can be compiled with either Visual Studio, the Windows SDK, which includes the Visual Studio C++ compiler, or GCC. Can you confirm which you’re using?

Comment: Scratch that, it seems that hxcpp always wants to invoke the Visual Studio compiler on Windows. I’m not sure where I got the idea that it can use GCC.

Comment: Also are you building with the Haxe compiler directly (`haxe -cp src -cpp bin -main Main -debug`), or with the NME command-line tool (`nme test windows -debug`)?

Comment: This is compiling using FlashDevelop + NME, so the latter, I do believe.